# CSS :first-child unexpected result when element has another element before

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set a margin-top of 20px to all my paragraph elements excepting the first one. I've this code:

```
    <div>
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Paragraph 1</p>
            <p>Paragraph 2</p>
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
div p{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
div p:first-child{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

But this isn't working... I think it's because of the , but I can't figure out how to fix it... I'm sure you can help me out!
I apologize if I messed up with my english, I hope I made myself clear!

Thanks!!!

Comment: in that case the first p isn't first-child.. h3 is the first child ;) (use a class?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a margin-top of 20px to all paragraph elements in a sequence of such elements excepting the first one, use

```
p + p { margin-top: 20px; }
```

If you additionally wish to set the margin top of the first `p` element in a sequence to zero, as it seems, just add

```
p { margin-top: 0; }
```

The rule with a more specific selector will override this for any element except the first one in a sequence.

The selector `div p:first-child` does not work, because it matches a `p` element that is the first child of its parent and a descendant of a `div` element. In your example, no `p` element is the first child of its parent.

Comment: I actually like this solution more then than accepted answer. It is far more to the intended goal of the OP.

Comment: Unlike the previous answer I don't need to worry about what element is on top of my paragraphs, so I find it even better and ready to use it in a lot more of situations. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`p` in your example isn't first child, `h3` is. Go with:

```
div h3 + p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fSZWU/

Answer (score 2):

The **pseudo-class `:first-child`** doesn't indicate *the first element of that type which is child of its parent*. It rather means the **first child element of its parent**.

I remember being confused at first as well, because I was expecting `:first-child = first`. The solution proposed by @yabol (`h3 + p`) will get you the paragraph next to the h3, which, in your case, is the first `<p>`; but be careful because by changing the structure of your page you might lose that particular style.

To achieve exactly what you are looking for, you have to use the **[CSS3 pseudo class `:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)**. Be careful though with the support (only IE9+!)

<kbd>[**Try it out yourself!**](http://jsbin.com/ebahac/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: In other words, "first child" is exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Indeed it does, but perhaps it may be confusing to non-native English speakers. I know it was for me when I started many years ago, so I thought I might state it clearly.